# switch that closes when power is on

Tags: switches, gpio, io

I'm currently working on a project that makes a device "IoT-ready".
So im looking for a switch, which got two inputs and two outputs.

When I close the circuit on the one side, it should close it on the other side, too.

Is there something available which does what im looking for?

Comment: Are you looking to build or buy this?  Unfortunately shopping questions are off-topic, but if you are designing this you should list what you have tried so far.

Comment: I thought there might be a general term for that component. To answer your question i want to buy that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need to buy a relay. It has an activation coil that can be energized usually with a few hundred milliwatts and this can open or close electrical contacts for use by an independent circuit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want both circuits on at the same time but still be independent from each other you want a "Double Pole Single Throw" switch, usually having 4 pins.  Wire the input power to any of the two end pins and each separate circuit to the other end pins.

If you want one circuit to go on and the other to go off (at the same time) you want to use a "Double Pole Double Throw" switch, usually having 6 pins, then wire each input power to the center pins but each circuit input to the opposite corner pins.

When buying a switch from a catalog they usually show you the basic diagram of how the pins match up internally to make the correct connections.

Comment: May I didnt explain it good enough. I want to have a switch, which closes on the one side if on the other side the power flows. If not it should be open.

Comment: Still something lost in translation here.  But assuming you mean switching the other circuit on if power is lost on another circuit then a relay (as in the earlier response) is a good idea.  Just be sure to get one with a NC (normally closed) connection.  More common would be a relay with both NC and NO connections - for example a Relay listed as having a single pole double throw output.

Comment: Okay sorry, i will try to explain it another way. I got a device with gpio pins. And these should replace normal buttons in a electronic device, like a coffee machine. So if i power the gpios, the coffeemachine should Start or the tv turns on or something like that. Hope its more clear now.